# Can't find memory error

Tags: c++, memory, polymorphism

I'm proggraming a bank simulation, as a polymorphism exercise, but I'm getting some memory errors.
I can malloc the first item of each vector, but if I call any of it's functions, the program crashes.
The same occurs if I try to malloc any number of items other than 1; (ncp or ncc >1 in the malloc cast)

```
int main(){
ContaPoupanca *contasp;
ContaCorrente *contasc;
int k = 0;
int ncp = 3;
int ncc = 3;
(...)
    switch(k){
        case 1: {
            int asd;
            std::string nome_titular;
            int n_conta;
            std::cout<<"\n 1 - Corrente \n 2 - Poupança";
            std::cin >> asd;
            std::cout<<"\nNome do Titular: ";
            std::cin>> nome_titular;
            if(asd == 1){
                std::cout<<"nº de aplicações: (max 5)\n";
                std::cin>>asd;
                if(asd>5) asd=5;
                if(asd<0) asd=0;
                    ncc++;
                    n_conta = ncc + 2501000 - 1;
                    contasc = (ContaCorrente*) malloc(ncc*sizeof(ContaCorrente));
                    contasc[ncc-1] = ContaCorrente(nome_titular,n_conta,1.07,0,asd);
            }else{
             ncp++;
             n_conta = ncp + 2502000 - 1;
             contasp = (ContaPoupanca*) malloc(ncp*sizeof(ContaPoupanca));
             contasp[ncp-1] = ContaPoupanca(nome_titular,n_conta,1.05,0);
            }
            std::cout<<"\nConta criada com sucesso.\n O nº da conta é "<<n_conta<<"\n";
            break;
        (...)
        case 6: {break;}
        }
    }while(k!=6);
free(contasc);
free(contasp);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: If you are in C++, there's basically no reason to use `malloc`.  Use a proper container (e.g. `std::vector`) instead.

Comment: Also, please don't just dump hundreds of lines of code.  You should work to find the *smallest* program that causes the issue, and then post that instead.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use malloc or free on C++ objects. Use new and delete instead.

malloc does not call any of your constructors, free does not call any of your destructors. That's why you get a crash. new and delete do.

Comment: Thanks. 
I rewrote my code using vectors, as Oli sugested and it's working now.
Thanks.